# Groovy/Grails, thread safety and closures

Tags: grails, groovy, thread-safety, closures

I'm investigating what looks like a race condition in my Grails application. I occasionally see what I think can only be the result of 2 different threads interfering with one another when the application is under a lot of load.

The offending code builds a query using a closure (which is defined at class-level, like a method) which dynamically adds query parameters based on the properties of the domain class. On the surface the code looks fine (to me, as a Java developer), however I stumbled across this comment regarding controller scope in the Grails docs (emphasis mine):

> prototype (default) - A new controller will be created for each request **(recommended for actions as Closure properties)**
>
> session - One controller is created for the scope of a user session
>
> singleton - Only one instance of the controller ever exists **(recommended for actions as methods)**

[Reference](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.x/ref/Controllers/scope.html)

So my question is: what are the implications of using a closure (instead of a method) in a service which is a singleton?

**EDIT:**

The code is part of the grails quick search plugin:

https://github.com/tadodotcom/grails-quick-search/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugins/quickSearch/QuickSearchService.groovy

There are 2 closures, `aliasBuilder` and `propertyQueryBuilder` which I think may not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Should you still need a solution, I just happened to fork that plugin and I stumbled upon the same problem (in the same concurrent scenario).

The long story short, helped by [this post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2010/06/groovy-goodness-synchronized-annotation.html), I applied the @Synchronized annotation to the search method of QuickSearchService service and the exception (NPE btw) went away.

HTH

Comment: I appreciate your response - I also ended up forking the plugin to resolve this. I'm no longer working on the project, but perhaps you'd consider issuing a pull request for the fix, or raising a defect on github?